# Merge two branches not master

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a branch I created which is a decendant of master.

```
master -> mybranch
```

I now need to merge in code from things/bugfix into mybranch

```
master -> things/bugfix
```

So I need things/bugfix code to be in mybranch

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First checkout `mybranch` :

`git checkout mybranch`

Then merge `things/bugfix` into `mybranch` :

`git merge things/bugfix`